# Springboot with Oauth 2.0 logging request and responses

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, maskedtextbox

Building SpringBoot application and using 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:3.0.2' trying to log the request and responses. I get  headers={masked}, trying to get details about request and responses.

Tried many things but no luck. I added below to yaml file, but still the same issue.

`
logging:
level:
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions: TRACE
pattern:
console: "%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
encoder:
mask:
headers:
- "authorization"

spring.codec.log-request-details: true

But still getting headers={masked} I want to see the request and the response.

`return  WebClient.builder() .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.builder().codecs { it.defaultCodecs().enableLoggingRequestDetails(true) }.build()) .filter(oauth) .build()`